# Google mobile vision api with Xamarin forms support for QR code

Tags: xamarin.forms

Google mobile vision API with xamarin forms support for QR code. I need some sample application.

Comment: I'm afraid the Google Cloud Client libraries aren't supported on Xamarin.forms . Why dont you use ZXing.Net library ? https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/qr-code-scanner-in-xamarin-forms2/

Comment: From the official close reasons: _Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it._